# Declaring a datetime variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I was wondering if I could grab a StartDate and an EndDate from a database table instead of assigning the StartDate and EndDate parameters as shown below? I already have the dates in another table. I need to get the data between those two dates.

```
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '1/4/2015' 
    DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '5/20/2015'
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT`.

Comment: I know I could.  What happened when you tried?

Comment: Declare '@StartDate' SELECT '@StartDate' = MyValue FROM MYTable

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql#setting-a-value-in-a-transact-sql-variable) on variables explains how you can use a `SELECT` statement to assign the value of a variable. For the basics, it is worth while having a look there first. It'll help you learn much more than having someone give you the answer without looking. :)

Comment: A lot of down votes on answers here with not comments

Comment: PSA: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: Have you done any research at all???  Have you check the documentation???  There are tons of example online.  If you put some effort searching, you wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo
Note you will get the last date read and there is no natural order so you need a unique sort to get a good assignment.

```
declare @dates table(iden int identity primary key, d1 datetime, d2 datetime) 
insert into @dates values ('1/1/1910', '1/2/1910'), ('1/1/1915', '1/2/1915');
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = (select top (1) d.d1 from @dates d);
DECLARE @EndDate   DATETIME;

SELECT @StartDate = d.d1, @EndDate = d.d2 
FROM @dates d;

select @StartDate, @EndDate 

SELECT top (1) @StartDate = d.d1, @EndDate = d.d2 
FROM @dates d 
order by d.iden;

select @StartDate, @EndDate 

----------------------- -----------------------
1915-01-01 00:00:00.000 1915-01-02 00:00:00.000             
----------------------- -----------------------
1910-01-01 00:00:00.000 1910-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

In the declare line you need to use ( ) and only return 1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the dates from another table just use

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE  @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT @StartDate = NameOfStartDateColumn, @EndDate = NameOfEndDateColumn
FROM TableName
```

And as mentioned in the comments if TableName contains more than 1 row you can add a WHERE clause onto the above to select the row you are after.

Comment: Don't understand the down vote.  This is correct as far as I know.

Comment: As long as `TableName` has exactly one row ... .

Comment: @HABO It still execute with more than one row.   See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the values to the variable in a `SELECT` statement:

```
DECLARE @MyVar DATETIME;
SELECT @MyVar = MyDateTimeColumn FROM MyTable WHERE ...;
```

Be aware, that only one value will be assigned to the variable, make sure, that your select statement returns only one record to prevent unpredictable results!

You can of course assign an aggregated value to the variable, such as the result of a MIN/MAX/SUM/etc function:

```
SELECT @MyVar = MAX(MyDateTimeColumn) FROM MyTable;
```

In this case, I would highly recommend to provide a default value in case there is no result returned:

```
SELECT @MyVar = ISNULL(MAX(MyDateTimeColumn), '2200-01-01') FROM MyTable;
```

You can assign values to multiple variables in one query, but you have to assign all columns to a variable:

```
SELECT
     @MyVarMin = ISNULL(MIN(MyDateTimeColumn), '1900-01-01')
   , @MyVarMax = ISNULL(MAX(MyDateTimeColumn), '2200-01-01')
FROM
  MyTable;
```

Now, to validate, that you have the correct value:

```
SELECT @MyVar;
```

You can use your variable in any subsequent queries as usual.

You can also join your source table to the parameter table, the actual solution depends on your data model and on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, you have one table with data, which contains one column of type `datetime` and another table that contains the desired date range, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dates](
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And now you want to select data from your data table (let's call it `MyData`) which is in the range defined by the entries in your `Dates` table, right?

Then you can just make a subselect

```
SELECT *
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[MyData]
WHERE Date between (SELECT BeginDate FROM dbo.dates) and (SELECT EndDate FROM dbo.dates)
```

Comment: As long as `dbo.dates` has exactly one row ... .

Comment: @HABO of course in any real scenario you would have additional columns and also add a WHERE condition to the sub select. The OP didn't really give too many details of what he wants.